# Is there a way to check for multiple types of children using PropTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-proptypes

Right now I have a Button component with contains multiple children (Icon and a String). Is there a way to check for both using PropTypes? At the moment I'm using **oneOfType** but it doesn't account for both being used at the same time. Basically, I want to be able to have a string with or without an icon on my button.

```
<Button onClick={doSomething}>
     <Icon></Icon> Example
</Button>


Button.propTypes = {
     children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
         PropTypes.element,
         PropTypes.string         
     ])
}
```

Comment: `PropTypes.node` covers any valid React child and is the standard to use for this.

Comment: That seems to work just fine. Is there a way to explicitly only allow an icon and string?